# Pimcore: Getting the White-Screen-of-Death after successful admin login

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404, pimcore

I've installed Pimcore on a VPS through Liquid Web. I loaded the sample data install which also uses the nightly build code. While everything installed fine, the public facing website appears fine and functions well, as does the login screen for the admin panel, once you log in, you see three black pulsing dots in the middle of a white screen, where eventually they disappear and you're simply left with a white screen.

Upon inspection of the error console, I'm seeing this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/website/var/tmp/minified_javascript_core_b18dd1d6984052da2ab5abc79f0c4a17.js?_dc=3704
```

Other scripts are also failing because this script isn't being loaded, so I'm fairly sure that once this script loads the others will work just fine.

When I try to directly access this JS file, I see this message:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Filtered by error handler (static file exception)
```

I have verified that the file exists in the filesystem, so I know for sure that it's there, leading me to believe that the filesystem has that directory and/or file locked down. Permissions etc, are all set to their appropriate values.

Pimcore Version 4

Comment: Are you sure the GET is an error? Might it possibly be the output of a RESTful server, maybe?

Comment: Are you sure that the apache/nginx user can access the file? PHP user and Apache user can be different.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Positive, as explained attempting to directly access the files results in a 404. Edited post, see above.

Comment: @IgorBenko I've already checked this. I can open edit and modify it. It seems to be that the web client simply is being blocked from accessing it.

Comment: Your user maybe can edit it, but the apache user probably can't. Run this command: `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` to find out the user of your webserver. Then try editing the file by doing this: sudo -u apache_user_from_previous_command vi your_file.js

Comment: @IgorBenko same user, same perms, there's no distinction between the two.

Comment: Try opening this file /website/var/config/system.php and temporarily change devmode to true. This should disable the minification. And try to load directly non minified files.

Comment: @IgorBenko I do not seem to have that path, I'm on CentOS 7. Not incredibly familiar with where things live.

Comment: This is a document root relative path not system path.

Comment: @IgorBenko You win the internet for today! We have interface!

Comment: @GrafikMatthew woohoo, that's a good sign :) Now try to clear the cache - the command is in the menu on the left under Settings. Then disable  devmode and see if the things still work.

Comment: @IgorBenko Clearing the cache worked, however, turning devmode off, seems to have presented the same issue, white screen is back.

Comment: Sorry, I thought "Clear temporary files". It's in the same submenu.

Comment: Clear Temporary Files worked, turning devmode off, still produces a white screen.

Comment: @GrafikMatthew I still think this is a permission issue. Your server (apache) can't access the files that are generated by PHP.

Comment: Strange that I only have this issue with Pimcore though. Wordpress, Drupal and Joomla do not give us this hassle, and they generate files on install as well. Not to mention, the dev mode should not really make a difference if it is in fact a permissions issue. Dev mode would not provide enough elevation at the OS level to make a difference, at least in theory.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years and this project surfaced in our pipeline again. The actual cause for why this breaks was because we are also running the ModSecurity suite on our host. Accessing the interface .js file was triggering rule `2000009` where the pattern `/var/tmp` was being matched.

**Possible solution (if you're using WHM/CPanel as we are):**

Configure your `/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec2/whitelist.conf` file to include the following rule (add more in the same place if needed).

```
<LocationMatch '/website'>
  SecRuleRemoveById 2000009
</LocationMatch>
```

*Be sure that you restart your HTTP service after making this update.*

Enjoy!